# iOS Autumation Script on custom control doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, custom-controls

I'm playing with automation script and I'm trying to accesso to a control on my view. This control inherits from `UIControl` and works as a button.

I set this property in order to access to the component:

[image]

so at this point I expect an automatic tap on the button by this script:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();

window.scrollViews()[0].buttons()["ButtonLogin"].tap();
```

but it is not so because it doesn't find `ButtonLogin`.
The only way to get that control pressed is by the static text:

```
window.scrollViews()[0].staticTexts()["Log in"].tap();
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work for me because I can have different languages and so the "*Log in*" text could change.

I need so a universal way to access to that control. With normal `buttons` and `textFields` it works properly setting an identifier for **accessibility** (like the image above), but in this case seems not working.

I also tried by:

```
window.scrollViews()[0].elements()["ButtonLogin"].tap();
```

without success.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

at the end for now I solved referencing to the index in the views hierarchy:

```
window.scrollViews()[0].staticTexts()[0].tap();
```

But anyway I want to use accessibility as the views hierarchy may change.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW21). Basically you should use accessibilityIdentifier property.